# Initialize the Google Mobile Ads SDK - mainactivity

Tags: java, android, android-layout, admob, ads

I have some doubts.
I am using admob banners in 3 different activities.
MainActivity | Activity1 | Activity2

I only initialize google mobile ads sdk in the main page (MainActivity). (advertising works well in all activities)

Would it be correct or would I have to initialize the google mobile ads sdk in each of the activity pages? ->  MobileAds.initialize(...){...}

**Code MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for your answers

Answer (score 0):

You should call `MobileAds.initialize()` before ad requests to prepare GMA SDK. Just call it once in the main activity or your first screen.

But even if you do not initialize it, Google Mobile Ads will be initialized at the first ad request.

Another point is that you are initializing mobile ads with an empty `OnInitializationCompleteListener`. It does nothing. You can also use **`MobileAds.initialize(this);`**